# Keep videos from resizing in MPlayer

Tags: mplayer

I'm trying to watch a movie with Movie Player, but it resizes the movie to fit the window, which messes with the quality. Is there a way to keep it from resizing while keeping the window maximized?

=/.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 2 ways to control the aspect ratio of mplayer.

You can set the aspect ratio of the monitor, and the aspect ratio of the video.

**To set the monitor aspect ratio**

```
mplayer -monitoraspect <ratio> <file.avi>
```

**To set the movie aspect ratio**

```
mplayer -aspect <ratio> <file.avi>
```

In your case `mplayer -aspect 4:3 <file.avi>` should keep it from resizing.

Comment: Maybe you can add which windowmanager you are using because it doesn't work with all of them.